# Cramer's Rule Proof Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have read the following proof on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#cite_note-12)

[image]

How does $X_1$ columns are $A^{-1}b,A^{-1}v_2,...,A^{-1}v_{n'}$ are they to columns augmented? or are they matrix multiplication ?

Comment: $A^{-1}v_i$ here denotes matrix multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are multiplication of the matrix $A^{-1}$ by vectors $\vec{x}, v_2, ..., v_n$. Your original equation is $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$, which transforms to $\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{b}$. This corresponds to the first column.

For the other columns, notice that $A^{-1}A=I_n$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix. So $A^{-1}$ multiplying by the $k$-th column of $A$ is the $k$-th column of $I_n$, which is exactly the $k$-th column of your $X_1$.

Answer (score 2):

We note the following about matrix multiplication: let $M,A$ be square matrices such that $MA$ is defined, and let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ denote the columns of $A$.  We then have
$$
MA = M\pmatrix{v_1&v_2&\cdots & v_1} =
\pmatrix{Mv_1 & Mv_2 & \cdots & Mv_n}
$$
Now, taking $A$ to be square and invertible, letting $M = A^{-1}$, and noting that $A^{-1}A = I$, we see that
$$
I = A^{-1}A = \pmatrix{A^{-1}v_1 & A^{-1}v_2 & \cdots & A^{-1}v_n}
$$
Thus, if $v_j$ is the $j$th column of $A$, then $A^{-1}v_j$ is the $j$th column of the identity matrix.

We then note that $A^{-1}b = x$ since $x$ is defined as the solution to $Ax = b$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $X_1$ as you can see it in the Wiki, can be rewritten as $$X_1=(A^{-1}b \ | \ A^{-1}v_2 \ | \  \dots \ | \  A^{-1}v_n).$$
This is the matrix with columnvectors $A^{-1}b, A^{-1}v_2,  \dots,   A^{-1}v_n$.

To see this, we compare the matrices column by column.
The first column of the original $X_1$ is given by the vector $x$. Which is exactly $A^{-1}b$, since we are considering the system $Ax=b$.

The other columnfollow from the fact that $A^{-1}A=I$. Writing this for each column $v_i$ of the matrix $A$ we see that $A^{-1}v_i=e_i$.

Comment: \*column, not collom